# Passing printf() as an argument to itself: printf("%",printf("%s", "something something"));

Tags: c

This is like a bit of a puzzle... I've just come back to C again with the intention of mastering it this time. So I have been reading *[The C Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)*, and I came by this statement:

> Among others, printf also recognizes ... %% for itself.

Something I didn't know earlier. So I started to play with this feature by writing this small piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int number = 300;
    printf("%\n\n%12d\n\n\n\n\n", printf("%\n\n\n\n\n\n", printf("%s", "foooo!")), number);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And here's the output:
[image: Output screenshot]

I would expect **300** in the output. Where does the **2** come from - does anyone know?

### **EDIT**

I realise this was totally a mistake due to my misunderstanding of the text I cited above. Thanks one and all for helping me realise that.

Comment: You nowhere have `%%` in your code, so how is the introduction related to what you actually did?

Comment: "Among others, printf also recognizes ... %% for itself" -- that's badly worded, but it certainly doesn't mean what you're taking it to mean. %% is the way to print % ... it's not a way to print the results of printf.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not passing valid combinations of arguments to two out of three `printf()` calls. This results in [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

> Among others, printf also recognizes ... `%%` for itself.

What this means is that `%%` in the format specifier results in a `%` being written to the output.

It has nothing to do with passing the return value of `printf()` (which is the number of characters written) to another `printf()` call. And, besides, your code doesn't even contain `%%`.

Comment: You are right... I misunderstood, the statement. This happens when one is expecting too much.. Guess I made that one up under the influence of my expectations.

Comment: @NPE Other words all this means (`%%`) is that it will just print "%"? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig: In a word, yes.

Answer (score 2):

```
A % followed by another % character will write a single % to the stream.
```

It sees `%` followed by a `\n` which is not a valid format specifier. Your format string also does not match your arguments. The return value of `printf` is the number of characters successfully written. Therefore it is a number. If your format string does not match the number of arguments passed to `printf`, it is undefined behavior.

```
printf("%12d    %d ",          printf("%d",          printf("%s", "foooo!")), number);
        number  ret of printf--^       ret of printf-^
```